# TypeError, forms validators

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Trying to construct a reactive Angular form but getting a type error.
Here's the angular-html-

```html
<form [formGroup]="newUser" (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()'>
    <label>ID</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter Your ID" formControlName="Tz" required>
    <span *ngIf="Tz.errors?.minLength && Tz.touched">Your ID must be at least 4 digits long</span>
    <span *ngIf="Tz.errors?.maxLength && Tz.touched">Your ID must be at most 9 digits long</span>
    <span *ngIf=""></span>
    <br>
    <label>Email</label>
    <br>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email" formControlName="Email" required>
    <span *ngIf="Email.invalid &&Email.touched">Your email does not look right</span>
    <br>
    <label>Password</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Please Choose A Password" formControlName="PW" size="25" required>
    <br>
    <label>Resubmit Your Password</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Please Resubmit Your Password" formControlName="PWVerification" size="30" required>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="newUser.invalid">
</form>
```

Here's the typescript:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators , FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { RegisterService } from '../register.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  public newUser;
  public verification;
  constructor(public RS: RegisterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newUser = new FormGroup({
      Tz: new FormControl ('',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(4),Validators.maxLength(9)]),
      Email: new FormControl ('',[Validators.required,Validators.email]),
      PW: new FormControl ('', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$')]),
      PWVerification: new FormControl ('', Validators.required)
    })
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.newUser.value);

    /*this.RS.RegisterUser(this.newUser.value).subscribe(

    )*/
  }
}
```

I am sure I am missing something but I simply can't put my finger on it.

Also, it the required attribute on the angular HTML necessary if I have set validators.required to all formcontrolnames on the TS side or is it redundant?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: There was a type error which was rectified by calling the formgroup instead of the individual form control names. Trying to figure out why
`

`

Answer (score 2):

```
<span *ngIf="Email.invalid &&Email.touched">Your email does not look right</span>
```

I believe your error is about this code. `Email` is not a field, it is only a form control **name**. You need to refer to the form instead and get the required form field.

```
<span *ngIf="newUser.get('Email').invalid && newUser.get('Email').touched">Your email does not look right</span>
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to have fixed the email field.
However for the ID field (minimum 4 digits, max 9 digits), no *ngIF error is coming up.
changed it to:
`<span *ngIf="newUser.get('Tz').errors?.minLength && newUser.get('Tz').touched">Your ID must be at least 4 digits long</span>
                        <span *ngIf="newUser.get('Tz').errors?.maxLength && newUser.get('Tz').touched">Your ID must be at most 9 digits long</span>
`

Comment: I agree. To eliminate the redundant `newUser.get('...')` calls you can create a getter in the component class for each field, such as `get Email() { return this.newUser.get('Email'); }` Then the code in your markup can remain as-is.